# Unable to connect to 'http://localhost/parse' and Cannot POST /parse/classes/GameScore

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform

I have Ubuntu 16.o4. Using [this](https://tecadmin.net/install-parse-server-on-ubuntu/) tutorial I setup node.js, parse-server and mongodb. Here is my index.js

I install node.js 9.x and mongodb 3.6

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp',
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAPP',
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || 'myMASTER', //Add your master key here. Keep it secret!
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',  // Don't forget to change to https if needed
  liveQuery: {
    classNames: ["Posts", "Comments"] // List of classes to support for query subscriptions
  }
});
```

When i try to

```
npm start
```

i got this one message:

```
> parse-server-example@1.4.0 start /root/parse-server-example
> node index.js

DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.
parse-server-example running on port 1337.

WARNING, Unable to connect to 'http://localhost:1337/parse'. Cloud code and push notifications may be unavailable!
```

Then i install dashboard:

```
sudo npm install -g parse-dashboard
```

In dashboard i create custom class with rows and everything saved fine.

But when i try to add some data using curl:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: myAPP" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"score":1337,"playerName":"Sammy","cheatMode":false}' \
  http://myIP:1337/parse/classes/GameScore  // or http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/GameScore
```

I've got an error:

```
Cannot POST /parse/classes/GameScore
```

I will be thankfull if somebody help me with it errors